# R count consecutive days with condition

Tags: r, date

I have the next question. If I have the next dataframe

```
data<- data.frame(
        Time= c("2018-01-01", "2018-01-02", "2018-01-03", "2018-01-04", "2018-01-05"),
        TEN= c(10,20,11,12,16)
    )
```

and I want to count the consecutive days that TEN < 15 as a new column **using R**.

I try with

```
waves_min <- function(df, prop, min_value, min_days) {
    sum(with(rle(df$Temp > min_temp), values & lengths >= min_days))
}
```

but it returns a total number of that count, not a value for each row.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: use cumsum if you want a cumulative sum

Comment: @JohnColeman edited, thanks

Comment: Can you show your expected output?

Answer (score 8):

### `dplyr` + `data.table::rleid`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

data %>%
  group_by(ID = data.table::rleid(TEN < 15)) %>%
  mutate(Consec_Days = if_else(TEN < 15, row_number(), 0L))
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   ID [5]
  Time         TEN    ID Consec_Days
  <fct>      <dbl> <int>       <int>
1 2018-01-01    10     1           1
2 2018-01-02    20     2           0
3 2018-01-03    11     3           1
4 2018-01-04    12     3           2
5 2018-01-05    16     4           0
6 2018-01-06    17     4           0
7 2018-01-07    14     5           1
```

### `data.table`:

```
setDT(data)
data[, Consec_Days := ifelse(TEN < 15, 1:.N, 0L), by = rleid(TEN < 15)]
```

**Output:**

```
         Time TEN Consec_Days
1: 2018-01-01  10           1
2: 2018-01-02  20           0
3: 2018-01-03  11           1
4: 2018-01-04  12           2
5: 2018-01-05  16           0
6: 2018-01-06  17           0
7: 2018-01-07  14           1
```

### Base R + `data.table::rleid`:

```
data$Consec_Days <- with(data, ave(TEN, data.table::rleid(TEN < 15), 
                                   FUN = function(x) ifelse(x < 15, seq_along(x), 0L)))
```

**Output:**

```
        Time TEN Consec_Days
1 2018-01-01  10           1
2 2018-01-02  20           0
3 2018-01-03  11           1
4 2018-01-04  12           2
5 2018-01-05  16           0
6 2018-01-06  17           0
7 2018-01-07  14           1
```

### Data:

```
data <- data.frame(
  Time= c("2018-01-01", "2018-01-02", "2018-01-03", "2018-01-04", "2018-01-05", "2018-01-06", "2018-01-07"),
  TEN= c(10,20,11,12,16,17,14)
)
```

I've added more rows to OP's sample data to illustrate that these solutions work for all cases. The basic idea is to look at the logical comparison `TEN < 15`, which returns a vector of bools. `rleid` then creates a vector of 'run length encoded ids' where it increments by one for every switch from `TRUE` to `FALSE` and vice versa. We then group by this `ID` column to count the number of consecutive days when `TEN < 15`.

Comment: I already liked the answer. But was does
group_by(ID = data.table::rleid(TEN < 15))
mean? Why is it necessary?

Comment: @ClemSnide Edited my answer with some explanation. Hope it helps.